# Laravel middleware verifyCsrfToken put variable

Tags: php, laravel

I need disable csrf token for certain referer. How I can do it?

I tried:

```
/**
 * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $except = [
    $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'http://example.com' ? '/example' : '',
];
```

But me get error: `expression is not allowed as field default value`

Comment: You cannot use expressions in a class definition. It needs to be a static value. Instead, assign it in the __construct method

Answer (score 0):

`$except` field is used to exclude specified URLs from CSRF checks. If you want to skip the check for requests from specific referer then you need to **extend** your `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware class and provide new `handle` method with something like this:

```
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @param \Closure                 $next
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    // If request comes from specific referer...
    if ($request->headers->get('referer') == 'http://example.com') {
        // ... then we append $except with URL to ignore.
        $this->except[] = '/example';
    }

    // After that we pass the control to original method's implementation
    // that will perform the check as usual.
    return parent::handle($request, $next);
}
```